# How to get list of trending github repositories by github api?

Tags: github-api

I want get list of github trending repos like this -https://github.com/trending?l=java
but i didnt find any similar request methods at https://developer.github.com/v3/ , how can i get  json responce with trending repos?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

GitHub seems to use their API to write the trending page and don't present it back as a particular API. You need to use the [Repository Search API](https://developer.github.com/v3/search/#search-repositories). I've followed the [examples on this page](https://gist.github.com/jasonrudolph/6065289), which could solve your needs by:

```sh
# We'll use the `date` command to get the date for "7 days ago"
$ date -v-7d '+%Y-%m-%d'
# => 2013-07-15

curl -G https://api.github.com/search/repositories --data-urlencode "sort=stars" --data-urlencode "order=desc" --data-urlencode "q=language:java"  --data-urlencode "q=created:>`date -v-7d '+%Y-%m-%d'`"
```

And then go from there. You can also make your life a lot easier by installing `jq` on [OS X](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/) or other platforms to get prettier output:

```sh
curl -G https://api.github.com/search/repositories --data-urlencode "sort=stars" --data-urlencode "order=desc" --data-urlencode "q=language:java"  --data-urlencode "q=created:>`date -v-7d '+%Y-%m-%d'`" | jq ".items[0,1,2] | {name, description, language, watchers_count, html_url}"
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- -- 77  161k   77  125k    0     0   131k      0  0:00:01 --:--:--  0100  161k  100  161k    0     0   163k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  163k
{
  "name": "vibrant.js",
  "description": "Extract prominent colors from an image. JS port of Android's Palette.",
  "language": "JavaScript",
  "watchers_count": 1466,
  "html_url": "https://github.com/jariz/vibrant.js"
}
{
  "name": "JSPatch",
  "description": "JSPatch bridge Objective-C and JavaScript using the Objective-C runtime. You can call any Objective-C class and method in JavaScript by just including a small engine.",
  "language": "Objective-C",
  "watchers_count": 830,
  "html_url": "https://github.com/bang590/JSPatch"
}
{
  "name": "KRVideoPlayer",
  "description": "类似Weico的播放器，支持竖屏模式下全屏播放",
  "language": "Objective-C",
  "watchers_count": 524,
  "html_url": "https://github.com/36Kr-Mobile/KRVideoPlayer"
}
```

Comment: nice, but if i am not mistaken,request with parameter "q=created:>`date" will return repositories that was created later then 7 days ago. I think trending repository is the one that got most stars ,despite date of creation

Comment: That parameter combined with `  --data-urlencode "sort=stars" --data-urlencode "order=desc"` gives you the most starred repos from the last week. You could filter that to less than a week if you'd like, but that's a good start!

Comment: That's not true. The same link you pointed out says this code is to "Find the hottest repositories created in the last week". The GitHub trending page is about the most starred items in a time range. There's no way to get this information with the current version of API. The solution I saw in other places was to parse trending page HTML.

Comment: I don't intend to mean you can get trends, but you could collect from every day since the request. Computationally easier to scrape the HTML page though.

Answer (score 4):

Currently there is no GitHub API to get list of trending repositories. The only way is to crawl items from web page by selectors. You can open https://github.com/trending in Chrome and run the following code in devtools console:

```
$$('ol.repo-list li h3').forEach(el => console.log(el.innerText));
```

This will output the list of trending repositories names. To make it more automated consider [Headles Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome) or other similar tools.

Also there are several projects that already have solved this task in different languages. For example:

- [vitalets/github-trending-repos](https://github.com/vitalets/github-trending-repos)
- [andygrunwald/go-trending](https://github.com/andygrunwald/go-trending)
- [sheharyarn/github-trending](https://github.com/sheharyarn/github-trending)
- etc

Answer (score 2):

It seems GitHub does not provide an official API to the public to achieve such use-case.
However, you can use one of the projects that can fulfill that easily for you. You can try [github-trending-api](https://github.com/huchenme/github-trending-api) project on GitHub and achieve exactly that.

```
$ch = curl_init();
$url = 'https://github-trending-api.now.sh/repositories?language=&since=daily'

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
```

This will fetch for you today's trending projects on GitHub. 
Good luck.

Comment: It's 2020 and I am trying out this solution but I get a 451 error. I need help

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to make a android application for above use case and found [this](https://github-trending-api.now.sh/repositories) api very use full and can give `language` and `since` as optional params to get repo specific to a language and trending for number or day's.

> `https://github-trending-api.now.sh/repositories?since=daily`

[Reference](https://githubtrendingapi.docs.apiary.io/#reference/0/repositories/list-trending-repositories)

Comment: this api has since gone down. an alternative has gone up https://github.com/alisoft/github-trending-api, but it should be noted these apis might go down at any time as they are supported by developers not an org