# Trending github repositories with github API

Tags: javascript, github, github-api

I want to get a list of github trending javascript repos this week, sorted by stars.

I found an old response on here that said there was no way to get it, is it still not possible?

Comment: Possible answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30525330/how-to-get-list-of-trending-github-repositories-by-github-api

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get list of trending github repositories by github api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30525330/how-to-get-list-of-trending-github-repositories-by-github-api)

Comment: "Currently there is no GitHub API to get list of trending repositories." Has anything changed?